# How to disable chrome --enable-crashpad process?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, fedora

Every time I quit the chrome browser, this process remains active. As far as I recall, previously, when I closed the browser, all processes associated with Chrome were also closed. Somehow, it is bothering and killing resources. How do I disable it? I am currently using fedora35-gnome.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I am interested in this question. if you found the answer, please answer !